# Reset JPA generated value between tests

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit4

I'm running spring + hibernate + JUnit with springJunit4runner and transactional set to default rollback I'm using in-memory derbydb as Database. Hibernate is used as a JPA Provider and I am successfully testing CRUD kinds of stuff. However, I have a problem with JPA and the behaviour of @GeneratedValue

If I run one of my tests in isolation, two entitys are persisted with id 1 and 2. If i run the whole test suite the ids are instead 6 and 7. Spring does rollbacks just fine so there are only these two entitys in the database after addition and of course zero before. But behaviour of @GeneratedValue doesn't allow me to reliable findById unless I would return the Id from the

```
dao.add(Entity e) //method
```

I don't feel like doing that for the sake of testing, or is it a good practise to return the entity that was persisted so I should be doing it anyway?

Answer (score 5):

in our project we use spring boot and h2 in memory db for test, and we solved it with the following annotation on the tests classes:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

for example:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    @SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = Main.class
    )
    @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
    public class FooTest {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, you did notice this question is about 5 years old by now, so problem solved :) Good to see a modern approach though.

Comment: The solution works. Thanks for that. The problem is, that the Context is created with every single Test so the duration of all tests is much longer. I was hoping for something like a flag to add at @Transactional to indicate that the autogenerated ids should be resetetd too.

Comment: 'DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD' has a huge impact on the speed factor when used with a lots of tests. It creates the spring context for every single test, which is worse when used in test driven environments.

Answer (score 1):

Your tests shouldn't really be depending on particular ID values being generated.. ID assignment is the database & persistence layer's call, & not your responsibility to make assumptions about.

Doesn't `dao.add(Entity e)` set the ID/primary key property in the Entity? Normally Hibernate sets IDs before storing entities, for generated & sequence-allocated IDs at least.

(By the way, I strongly recommend using a portable (table-based) allocator and *never* depending on database-specific allocations mechanisms -- sequences or autoincrement columns. Portable allocators work faster & depending on proprietary key-allocation will make it very very much harder to ever run on a different database.)

In general, systems that save data *do* need a means of knowing what ID it has been saved to.. otherwise there would no reliable & unique means of retrieving it, which is the whole reason we have a PK in the first place!

So you might as well find out how to do it properly at this point.

Comment: I have converted id generation to table based. But the reason the test was relying on a hard-coded expected Id was because I couldn't get hold of the id through the entity because in the add(Entity e) method, under certain circumstances a copy of the provided entity was created and the persisting work was done on that copy so the Id did not update in the original object. It was a really stupid construct so I changed that too.

Comment: That sounds great.. should result in much more solid groundwork for the future development of your app, and getting that robust will make your life much easier long-term.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do it. Manually alter table to restart/reset the auto_increment value. As I use Derby DB it is done by the following sql query issued as a native query call since I as stated use JPA API

```
em.createNativeQuery("ALTER TABLE konsult ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH 1").executeUpdate();
```

It's pretty self-explanatory but basically you provide the table name and the auto incrementing column of that table and then choose which value the first persisted row should be given.

Here is the way to do it with mysql:
[Resetting auto-increment value of MySql database with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432797/resetting-auto-increment-value-of-mysql-database-with-jpa)

I'm still open to other suggestions though since this is sort of a hack and is in a way a dependency on other tests. It's also not RDBMS independent.